# french accent character issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, diacritics, non-ascii-characters

I am facing issue with french word (accent/special character) in javascript. e.g. Payable date pass�e de maturit� here It need to show exact character rather �. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Save all your HTML and JS files as UTF-8 and set the HTML `Content-Type` to UTF-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have set charset in meta and js script file and its working fine :)